# mongodb: pre-bake conf file to start replica set

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to set up a MongoDB replica set via `ansible`.

Therefore I am templating the following file (and it works)

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,{{ inventory_hostname }}


processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo


replication:
   replSetName: "{{ mongodb_replicaset_name }}"
```

What are the additions/modifications that I should make, so that one of the hosts becomes primary and the other two secondaries, without me havint to resort to the mongo cli?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/),

> Run rs.initiate() on just one and only one mongod instance for the replica set.

It appears you must connect via mongo CLI to at least one member of the replica set and initiate it.  From there the voting system should kick in automatically and one of the RS becomes primary.